# Storing user activity? PHP, MySQL and Database Design

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

Ok so a user comes to my web application and gets points and the like for activity, sort of similar (but not as complex) as this site. They can vote, comment, submit, favorite, vote for comments, write description etc and so on.

At the moment I store a user action in a table against a date like so

```
Table user_actions
    action_id       - PK AI int
    user_id         - PK int
    action_type     - varchar(20)
    date_of_action  - datetime
```

So for example if a user comes along and leaves a comment or votes on a comment, then the rows would look something like this

```
    action_id       = 4
    user_id         = 25
    action_type     = 'new_comment'
    date_of_action  = '2011-11-21 14:12:12';

    action_id       = 4
    user_id         = 25
    action_type     = 'user_comment_vote'
    date_of_action  = '2011-12-01 14:12:12';
```

All good I hear you say, but not quite, remember that these rows would reside in the `user_actions` table which is a different table to the ones in which the comments and user comment votes are stored in.

So how do I know what comment links to what row in the `user_actions`?

Well I could just link to the unique `comment_id` in the comments table to a new column, called `target_primary_key`      in the `user_actions` table?

Nope. Can't do that because the action could equally have been a `user_comment_vote` which has a composite key (double key)?

So the thought I am left with is, do I just add the primary keys in a column and comma deliminate them and let PHP parse it out?

So taking the example above, the lines below show how I would store the target primary keys

```
new_comment
target_primary_keys - 12 // the unique comment_id from the comments table 

user_comment_vote
target_primary_keys - 22,12 // the unique comment_id from the comments table
```

---

So basically a user makes an action, the `user_actions` is updated and so is the specific `table`, but how do I link the two while still allowing for multiple keys?

Has anyone had experience with storing user activity before?

Any thoughts are welcome, no wrong answers here.

Comment: I would not comma separate. If a users delete a comment and you want to clear up the activity you might run into issues. if you put an index on (action_type,target_primary_key)  you wont run into your key 'double key issue'.

Comment: The most appropriate, relational, way to connect data is via intersect tables. Thus, in your case, you'd maybe have a `user_comment_has_user_action` table that links `user_comment_id` to `user_action_id` (and vice versa). If the relationships are not important, don't bother with it and use what you have or some sort of programmatic way to remove actions.

Comment: Yes, thats what im battling with Kevin. It's an awkward one. Because there could 10 different `user_actions` which would account to 10 more tables. I think, I might go down the, let PHP parse it, route.

Comment: Lylo, this is the trouble. I understand that my model isn't the best, but as it stands i've spent 2 days thinking about this. Trust me, PHP is looking like a better option more and more

Comment: Sean, if you are just using this information to build up a point scheme, perhaps you don't need the action table or intersects and just need a view to spit out the rep number?

Comment: If there are ten different possible actions, just abstract; have a table with user_id, type, and fkey_id (which could be from any table); sorry its nebulous but it's hard to be more specific from your examples, which are also a bit nebulous ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is to just use another table, which can contain multiple matches for any key and allow great indexing options:

```
create table users_to_actions (
   user_id int(20) not null,
   action_id int(20) not null,
   action_type varchar(25) not null,
   category_or_other_criteria ...
);

create index(uta_u_a) on users_to_actions(user_id, action_id);
```

To expand on this a bit, you would then select items by joining them with this table:

```
select
  *
from
  users_to_actions as uta join comments as c using(action_id)
where
  uta.action_type = 'comment' and user_id = 25
order by
  c.post_date
```

Or maybe a nested query depending on your needs:

```
  select * from users where user_id in(
      select
         user_id
      from 
         users_to_actions
      where
         uta.action_type = 'comment'
  );
```

Comment: Im not sure how your answer is different to what I have in my question? I just can't figure the best way to store the multiple keys. Without having ugly NULL columns

Comment: You need to utilize an index table, which can contain multiple users, keys, etc; a composite key is silly and defeats the purpose of an  RMDB; your index table (in my example, users_to_actions) will serve as your composite key and contain all the relationships.

Comment: I think you may have mis-understood. The process of joining the table once the keys are stored is not a problem. Its simply, how do I store multiple keys when the key could be between 1 and 3 columns

Comment: I think it's simpler than you think :) You just put all the key columns in the db. If you need to match on missing parts of the key, just try something like `where (part_1='abc' or part_1 is null) and (part_2 > 123 or part_2 = 0)` and so on.

Comment: And I guess I just don't see the problem with null columns. ;) What's so ugly about them? They sure beat trying to deal with hashes and delimiters and other complex and silly ways of avoiding a simple join.

Comment: Ok, well I suppose it does make sense in order to keep the database relational. Well, it can't harm.

Comment: If you provide a working example, I'd be happy to work through it with you; just my sort of challenge ;)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a user actions table.
To calculate the "score" you can run one query over multiple tables and multiply the count of matching comments, ratings etc. with a multiplier (25 points for a comment, 10 for a rating, ...).

To speed up your page you can store the total score in an extra table or the user table and refresh the total score with triggers if the score changes.

If you want to display the number of ratings or comments you can do the same.

Get the details from the existing tables and store the total number of comments and ratings in an extra table.